# Thread Id Composition

Tags: email, case, case-object, email2case

I have been doing a lot of searching around Thread Id for Email to Case. I see the formula's everyone uses and I see a few apex examples to build the Thread Id. Does anyone know where the documentation around this might be?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315565&type=1&mode=1

Comment: No, I am looking for how it is made. We know it is a combination of the case id and org id. But where does it say it is x from case id and y from org id.